# how to stop input() from other thread in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, input

How can I stop or reach to avoid hanging of the following:

```
import threading
mythread = Threading(target = input_read, args = (callback))
mythread.start()
running = True

def callback(msg):
  if msg == 'stop': running = False
  print(msg)

def input_read(callback):
  while running:
    callback(input())

while running:
  try:
    # some other code
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Somehow the input should be stopped, time outted, killed, anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with setting the thread to daemon:
mythread.daemon = True
mythread.start()